# How to refresh one component from another component that saves the record in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, refresh

I have Component A that Shows the details of the record. The Details are coming from apex Controller.

I have Component B that has a lightining-button which on click shows a Modal for editing the same record that is displayed in Component A.

When I click on Save the record from Component B's Modal, it is updated at the backend, but the updatations are not immediately visible on ComponentA.

How can I Refresh the Component A , after the record is updated by Component B?

Component A has the following code that fetches the data from the controller

```
wiredFetchData({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('result:: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            this.data = data;
            console.log('data:: ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
            this.error = undefined;
            this.recordid = String(this.data[0].Id);
            this.name = this.data[0].Name;
            this.sourceObj = this.data[0].DYNMPR__SourceObject__c;
            this.targetObj = this.data[0].DYNMPR__TargetObject__c;
            this.description = this.data[0].DYNMPR__Description__c;
            this.active = this.data[0].DYNMPR__Active__c;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        refreshApex(this.data);
    }
```

component B has the following code that handles record edit

```
handleSubmit(){
        var dataList = {};
        dataList.Id = this.data[0].Id;
        dataList.Name = this.name;
        dataList.DYNMPR__Active__c = this.active;
        dataList.DYNMPR__SourceObject__c = this.sourceObj;
        dataList.DYNMPR__TargetObject__c = this.targetObj;
        dataList.DYNMPR__Description__c = this.description;;
        this.newData = dataList;
        this.newData = dataList;
        console.log("this.EditData:: " + JSON.stringify(this.newData));
        updateData({mapObjData : this.newData});
        this.closeModal();
      //  return refreshApex(this.newData);

    }
```

How do I displatch the refreshApex event from component b  after the save is handled as shown. I checked the guide but couldn't understand. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new Lightning Message Service, this is the alternative to the pub-sub model. You can publish a message from Component B post your operation and make Component A as a subscriber and then refresh the component.

Please refer to the below link for more details
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation

Comment: Hi suresh, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [answer] and take the tour if you haven't already. In the future, you don't need to `@mention` the person asking the question, as they'll automatically be notified of new answers. This also better fits our Q&A format. We look forward to your future contributions!

Answer (score 1):

One trick I found for this is to import the same apex method and implement it as a wire method in component B as well.

So let's say Component A had

```
@wire(getData)
wiredFetchData...
```

Implement the following in component B

```
 @wire(getData)
 wireForRefreshPurposes
```

Calling `refreshApex(this.wireForRefreshPurposes)` in component B would refresh wiredFetchData in component A as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Wire to get the record

You can make use of wire service to get the record in component A and once the updates get finished in component B, fire a custom event from Component B and listen to it on Component A. The event handler will make use of **refreshApex()** method.

> Sometimes, you know that the cache is stale. If the cache is stale,
>   the component needs fresh data. To query the server for updated data
>   and refresh the cache, import and call the refreshApex() function.
>   Invoke refreshApex() only when necessary because it incurs a network
>   trip to query the server.

```
   @wire(getOpptyOverAmount)
   opptiesOverAmount;

   handleClick() {
       refreshApex(this.opptiesOverAmount);
   }
```

To know how you can create and dispatch an event, refer here:- [Communicate with Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch)
To know more about apex method in LWC: - [Call Apex Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex)

Comment: I need more clarification as to how can I call the refreshView from component B post the record is saved. I have added a snippet of code above. @sanketkumar